# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to send data to a database using PHP but when I execute the query using `execute()` I get an error that says

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Code Sharing Website\submit_snippet.php on line 12

Here's my code

```
include 'includes/db.php';

if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['snippet'])) {
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $snippet = $_POST['snippet'];

  $snippet = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO all_snippets (snippet_name, snippet_body) VALUES (:title, :snippet)");
  $snippet->execute(array(
    ':title' => $title,
    ':snippet' => $snippet
  ));
} else {
  echo "Error: Please fill out all fields";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reassigning your `snippet` variable to a PDO object and then try to use that in your `execute`. One of those variables needs to be renamed.

Changing `$snippet = $_POST['snippet'];` to `$snippetPost = $_POST['snippet'];` and your `execute` to this should fix it.

```
  $snippet->execute(array(
    ':title' => $title,
    ':snippet' => $snippetPost
  ));
```